# preg_match() разбор строки "1.Черный (black.png)"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Использую `preg_match()` для разбора строки, которая может иметь несколько вариантов:

```
1.Черный (black.png)
   1.Черный (black.png)
Черный (black.png)
1.Черный
   1.Черный
Черный
```

Нужно чтобы там где указано возвращалось значение:
1) цифра до точки (если есть цифра с точкой)
2) после точки до круглой скобки (если есть или до конца строки)
3) то что в круглых скобках (если есть)

У меня получилось читать варианты без значения в круглых скобках:

```
/(^\d+)?\.?\s+?(.*)/u
```

Подскажите пожалуйста варианты или помогите советом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно отталкиваться от следующего варианта

```
$text = '1.Черный (black.png)';
$text = '   1.Черный (black.png)';
$text = 'Черный (black.png)';
$text = '1.Черный';
$text = '   1.Черный';
$text = 'Черный';
$pattern = '/^\s*(?:(\d+)\.)?([^\n]+?)(?:\(([^\)]+)\))?$/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Только вот хотелось бы без точки цифру в массиве увидеть и значение в круглых скобках без скобок.

Comment: @KirilLoveVE поправил ответ

Comment: array (
  0 => '1.Черный (black.png)',
  1 => '1',
  2 => 'Черный ',
  3 => '(black.png)',
)
А возможно значение (black.png) получить без круглых скобок?

Comment: @KirilLoveVE поправил ответ :)